# ConnectionManager error using typeorm implementing typedi

Tags: typescript, typeorm, typegraphql, typedi

I was trying to use typeorm with typedi, and there were some problem. I want to use typeorm for ORM, typegraphql for GraphQL, and DI for typedi. And now I'm trying to implementing typedi with typeorm, but there are some problem I get:

**Error I got**

```
{
  "message": "Cannot get Connection with name \"default\" from the ConnectionManager. Make sure you have created the connection and called \"useContainer(Container)\" in your application before establishing a connection and importing any entity into TypeORM.",
  "exception": {
    "connectionName": "default",
    "name": "ManagerNotFoundError",
    "stacktrace": [
      "ManagerNotFoundError: Cannot get Connection with name \"default\" from the ConnectionManager. Make sure you have created the connection and called \"useContainer(Container)\" in your application before establishing a connection and importing any entity into TypeORM."
    ]
  }
}
```

However, I'd already placed `useContainer(Container)` above the connection settings.

**src/index.ts** *(Entry File)*

```
import './utils/env'
import 'reflect-metadata'
import { Server } from './server'
import { Database } from './database'
import logger from './utils/logger'
import { Container } from 'typeorm-typedi-extensions'
import { useContainer } from 'typeorm'

const server = new Server()
const database = new Database()

useContainer(Container)

void database
  .connect()
  .then(() => {
    logger.info('Database connected')
    void server.listen().then((server) => {
      const { port } = server.address() as { port: number }
      logger.info(`Server started on port ${port}`)
    })
  })
  .catch((reason) => {
    throw new Error(`Databse Error: ${reason as string}`)
  })
```

And these is my userRepository file

**src/entities/user/UserRepository.ts**

```
@Service()
@EntityRepository(User)
export class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {
  // (...)
}
```

And this is my UserService file

**src/graphql/user/UserService.ts**

```
@Service()
export default class UserService {
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private readonly userRepository: UserRepository

    // (...methods)
}
```

Lastly, this is my UserResolver file

**src/graphql/user/UserResolver.ts**

```
@Service()
@Resolver(() => User)
export class UserResolver {
  @Inject()
  private readonly userService: UserService

  (...)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED :: `node_modules/typeorm-typedi-extensions/cjs/container-registrations.const.js`

Line 10

**FROM**

`typedi_1.Container.set({ id: typeorm_1.ConnectionManager, type: typeorm_1.ConnectionManager });`

**TO**

`typedi_1.Container.set({ id: typeorm_1.ConnectionManager, type: typeorm_1.ConnectionManager, global: true });`